# BackgroundDownloader.GetCurrentDownloadsAsync returns completed downloads

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

In my windows store app I am using BackgroundDownloader class to handle multiple background downloads. After all my 3 downloads are 100% complete, I close and open application, then when I run BackgroundDownloader.GetCurrentDownloadsAsync, it returns all downloads with 100% completed state.

```
IReadOnlyList<DownloadOperation> readOnlyList = await BackgroundDownloader.GetCurrentDownloadsAsync();
```

My expectation is completed downloads will be removed from list or somehow I need to force-remove them. But could not find any function for it.

How can I remove completed downloads from CurrentDownloads list?

-Side question: Will GetCurrentDownloadsAsync function return all active downloads (including other applications downloads) or only downloads are performing in my application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to execute the completion handler by doing `AttachAsync()` on the downloads that just completed. After that, downloads will not appear anymore in the results of `GetCurrentDownloadsAsync()`.

Try:

```
private async void Foo()
{
    var downloads = await BackgroundDownloader.GetCurrentDownloadsAsync();
    foreach (var download in downloads)
    {
        var task = download.AttachAsync().AsTask();
        var notAwait = task.ContinueWith(OnCompleted);
    }
}

private void OnCompleted(Task<DownloadOperation> task)
{
    DownloadOperation download = task.Result;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This is working like a charm. I believe lots of up-votes will rain here because there is no valid answer on Google results. Thanks!

Comment: This solution isn't working with me for some reason, After the download completed, if another request to the same uri called, It throws exception Bad request 400 even if  i called AttachAsync. The problem doesn't exist when I restart the application. Any Thoughts?

Comment: I figured it out, I was reusing the same BackgroundDownloader, I fixed it by instantiating a new instance of BackgroundDownloader each time I start a new download. I don't know if there are other ways to fix my issue but this one worked.

Comment: @Ahmed You may be setting headers in the `BackgroundDownloader` you do not need in both downloads.